# Tomcat SSL in Port 80

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I have configured SSL in tomcat in port 443 and I have URL redirection from 80 port to 443 automatically. I did neccesary configuration in web.xml too. It's working fine. But I have to use SSL in port 80 itself where I have to avoid the port 443 to be displayed in the URL which looks odd.

my app should be something like this... https://sub.example.com/myapp instead of https://sub.example.com:443/myapp

Help appreciated!

Comment: Actually port 443 is default for HTTPS and port number would not be displayed in such URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mistake.  I think it's a better idea to use the default HTTPS port and concentrate on changing the URL display.  You could have problems with firewalls that prefer the standard rules otherwise.

[Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=hiding%20port%20number%20in%20URL%20java&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS464US464&oq=hiding%20port%20number%20in%20URL%20java&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for "hiding port number in URL java" brought back lots of results, including this one:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/496635/Tomcat/Hiding-port-number-URL

Comment: I think I have to go for mod_proxy for this.